# Send welcome email on one time login via admin UI

Tags: users, emails, importing-exporting

I am Importing all my users into drupal but I don't want to send the welcome emails now.

When the site goes Live I want to be able to push a button or perform an action which sends all the users the welcome email and one time login URL so they can login and reset their password.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once imported, on the /admin/people page you can select all users and deactive the accounts. If you activate them again, they get the e-mail.

Comment: Don't forget to denote any users you have already blocked, so that you do not reactivate the ones that you want to keep blocked.